# Does Svelte facilitate dynamic CSS styling?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, how should classes be changed on elements depending upon component state?

For instance, you may wish to apply a class to a button under certain conditions, as in the following example.

```
<button class="{{class}}">
```

Right now, this can be achieved by creating a [computed property](https://svelte.technology/guide#computed-properties) which would return class names, or empty strings, under certain conditions.

However, I am concerned over whether this might be polluting the computed properties namespace. For instance, if there were a `status`, it might be desired to both set a dynamic text, like `statusMessage`, and a class, like `statusClass`.

Is there a better way to do this, or are computed properties the way to go? Is any more explicit support for CSS planned for Svelte?

Answer (score 14):

You can use an inline expression, like so:

```html
<button class='{{active ? "active": "inactive"}}'>
  {{active ? 'Selected' : 'Select this'}}
</button>
```

That's generally better than using a computed property, because it's immediately clear what the possible values are just by looking at the template.

You can also use helper functions, if the expression would become unwieldy — in some situations you might prefer these to computed values:

```html
<button class='{{getClass(status)}}'>{{getText(status)}}</button>

<script>
  export default {
    helpers: {
      getClass(status) {
        // ...
      },
      getText(status) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: As of today, the inline expression is ```<button class='{active ? "active": "inactive"}'>``` (one less bracket required, hooray!)

Comment: If you come from React you can also use the JSX like syntax : `<button class={\`${active ? "active": "inactive"}\`}>`

Answer (score 13):

Today you can use:

```
export let whitetext = false;
<div class:whitetext></div>
```

and then

```
<MyComponent whitetext={true} />
```

syntax for simple true/false based classes.

Comment: How do you set multiple classes this way?

Comment: Like this `<div class:whitetext class:issponsored class:offset></div>`

Answer (score 3):

There's no inbuilt way to use, e.g., conditionals like `{#if}` inside `class=`, per other popular frameworks.

Since inline expressions will become unwieldy as soon as you have more than two classes, I'd go straight to helpers in that case. Quick example of a class builder helper:

```js
helpers: {
    getSlideClasses(index, currentIndex) {
        let classes = ['js_slide']
        if ( index === currentIndex ) {
            classes.push('selected')
        }
        if ( index === 0 ) {
            classes.push('first')
        }
        return classes.join(' ')
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<div class='{ getSlideClasses(index, currentIndex)}'>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the tutorial it's:

```
<div class:active="{current === 'foo'}">
```

If the condition returns true, then the `active` class is added.

See: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes

```
<script>
    let current = 'foo';
</script>

<style>a
    button {
        display: block;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #ff3e00;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<button
    class="{current === 'foo' ? 'active' : ''}"
    on:click="{() => current = 'foo'}"
>foo</button>

<button
    class="{current === 'bar' ? 'active' : ''}"
    on:click="{() => current = 'bar'}"
>bar</button>

<button
    class="{current === 'baz' ? 'active' : ''}"
    on:click="{() => current = 'baz'}"
>baz</button>
```

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/be0bbe0d7e28439baf08a7c432a95ef8?version=3.22.0 svelte may facilitate dinamic css styles using nested components.