# Svelte conditional element class reported as a syntax error

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I am making an `if` block per the [Svelte Guide for if blocks](https://svelte.technology/guide#if-blocks). It seems simple enough, but Svelte thinks it's a syntax error:

```
[!] (svelte plugin) ParseError: Unexpected character '#'
public\js\templates\works.html
3:     <div class="slides js_slides">
4:       {#each works as work, index}
5:         <div class="js_slide {#if index === currentIndex }selected{/if} {#if index === 0 }first{/if}">
                                ^
6:           <img src="/images/work/screenshots/{ works[index].slug }-0.{ works[index].imageExtension }"/>
7:         </div>
```

Why isn't `{#if index === currentIndex }` considered valid? How can I do a conditional in Svelte?

Not I could create seperate `class=` blocks for **every possible outcome**, but that's a massive amount of work.

Comment: Blocks (`{#if...`, `{#each...` etc) can't be used inside attributes. Instead, the convention is to use ternary expressions (`{index === currentIndex ? 'selected' : ''} {index === 0 ? 'first' : ''}`, or to use a helper (e.g. `class={getClass(work, index, currentIndex)}`). Some people prefer to do things like `data-selected={index === currentIndex} data=first={index === 0}`

Comment: thanks — have moved my comment to an answer

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324684/does-svelte-facilitate-dynamic-css-styling

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Blocks (`{#if...`, `{#each...` etc) can't be used inside attributes — they can only define the structure of your markup.

Instead, the convention is to use ternary expressions...

```html
<div class="
  js_slide
  {index === currentIndex ? 'selected' : ''}
  {index === 0 ? 'first' : ''}
">
  <img src="/images/work/screenshots/{ works[index].slug }-0.{ works[index].imageExtension }"/>
</div>
```

...or to use a helper:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="js_slide {getClass(work, index, currentIndex)}">
  <img src="/images/work/screenshots/{ works[index].slug }-0.{ works[index].imageExtension }"/>
</div>
```

Some people prefer to do things like `data-selected={index === currentIndex}` and `data=first={index === 0}`, and style based on `[data-selected=true]` selectors instead.

Comment: Teneary expressions does not seem to work right now in svelte 3. BUG! See also this question: :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081289/condition-for-svelte-tag-attributes

Comment: What is the bug? Ternary expressions work fine: https://svelte.dev/repl/c45c86b0f3784013a7ab8e3c54a27e2d?version=3.12.1

Answer (score 11):

Since Svelte 2.13 you can also do

```
<div class:selected={index === currentIndex}>...</div>
```

See https://svelte.dev/docs#class_name

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://svelte.dev/docs#class_name  , it require extra JS variable to operate **if else** inside **class**

here is a example where a **each** loop iterate from **a** to **b** and when **if** is *true*  the css will be applied

```
{#each Array.from(Array(b+1).keys()).slice(a) as i }

    <div class="{ i===4 ? "border-l-2 border-blue-500" : ""}  p-3 space-y-4">
     some sample text
    </div>
{/each}
```

example (1 to 15) :

```
{#each Array.from(Array(15+1).keys()).slice(1) as i }

    <div class="{ i===3 ? "border-l-2 border-blue-500" : ""}  p-3 space-y-4">
     some sample text
    </div>
{/each}
```