# Condition for svelte tag attributes

Tags: svelte

How to add attribute inline, without needing to duplicate the anchor tag ?
https://svelte.dev/repl/a4e072ca670b481cb5d0360d01d07f27?version=3.12.1

```
<ul>    
    {#each menu as item}
        <li>
            <a
                {item.prefetch ? 'rel=prefetch' : ''}  
                href="{item.link}">
                {item.title}
            </a>
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

I have Error compiling component when:

```
{item.prefetch ? 'rel=prefetch' : ''}
```

Next code works, but not quite what I need:

```
rel={item.prefetch ? 'prefetch' : ''}
```

Comment: Why is the code that works not what you need?

Comment: @nash11 
if I write just
{item.prefetch ? 'rel=prefetch' : ''} - it not works

Comment: My question was, you have a code that works -> `rel={item.prefetch ? 'prefetch' : ''}`. Why is that not what you need? What is the problem with that?

Comment: Look at the repl: It does not work. A compile error states: Expected } (22:9) in this line: {item.prefetch ? 'rel=prefetch' : ''}

Comment: @voscausa - I know that code does not work, but it works if you use `rel={item.prefetch ? 'prefetch' : ''}` instead. Replace the code in the REPL and see. I just mentioned what was already in the OP. I'm just asking what's the problem with that solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `undefined` e.g.

```
            rel={item.prefetch ? 'prefetch' : undefined}
```

Which should give you:-

```
<ul>
<li><a rel="prefetch" href=".">Главная</a> </li>
<li><a href="about.html">О нас</a> </li>
</ul>
```

See:- 
https://svelte.dev/repl/31ab5879ed1b457a8a53e3cc70a0749f?version=3.12.1

Comment: It would be advisable to use the built-in code snippets here on Stack Overflow instead of linking to an external site for your demo.

Comment: I simple modified the OP external link to show the suggested change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>    
  {#each menu as {title, link, prefetch} }
  <li>
     {#if prefetch}
       <a rel="prefetch" href="{link}">{title}</a> 
      {:else}
       <a href="{link}">{title}</a>                  
      {/if}
    </li>
    {/each}
 </ul>
```

More here: [Svelte conditional element class reported as a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399018/svelte-conditional-element-class-reported-as-a-syntax-error)

But tenary expressions does not seem to work right now! BUG!

Comment: In this solution you use two <a> tags, I know about this (( . But I search solution without needing to duplicate the anchor tag

Comment: Ternary expressions do work. Conditional attributes like what is trying to be done in the OP, do not(See [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/259)).